# How do I figure out why a tomcat6 webapps dir symbolic link works on one machine, but not another?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, tomcat6, jsp

I recently built an Ubuntu virtual machine for MarkLogic development.  The machine was then distributed to 4 other developers to provide a consistent dev platform.  Now I'm setting up another piece to the dev puzzle that consists of some java libraries and a JSP web application.  The project source lives in the developer user home directory (each machine has the same exact account).  I added a symbolic link into the `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/` directory that points to the web application source root in the project directory.

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jspapp -> /home/developer/dev/workspace/svn/Project/webapp/
```

(The actual JSP files live in the Project/webapp directory.)

This works fine on my instance of the VM.  I successfully replicated the setup to one other VM and it worked fine.  However, the rest of the VMs on which I replicate the setup don't work.  On the first 2 VMs, I get the web app's pages.  On the other VMs I get 404s.

The VMs were all cloned from a single original.  All of the web app project source is the same except for 1 configuration value (the local machine's IP address).  I created the symbolic link in the same way on each and verified that permissions/modes of the files and directories are the same.  I compared the tomcat installation directories and see no configuration differences between them.  The only file differences I do see are what appear to be the cache data of Catalina.  For all intents and purposes, the setups are identical.  Yet, clearly, something is not the same.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can troubleshoot this problem?  I am rather new to the linux world and brand new to tomcat.

**Update** - I copied the contents of the linked directory into a real directory of the same name (after deleting the link) and it still doesn't work.  However, I *can* see a copy of `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/index.html` that I put into the directory in question.  It's behaving almost like the JSP files are getting ignored.

Comment: have you checked the tomcat logs yet?

Comment: I checked the logs and I don't see anything related to this problem.  Perhaps I can increase the verbosity of the logs...

Comment: I found `/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties` where I changed the logging level of `[Catalina].[localhost]` as well as uncommented 4 lines for `catalina.startup`, `catalina.session` & `catalina.core`. This seemed to have an affect. I get more log entries, but still nothing related to the error.

Answer (score 1):

A quick checklist:

1. Check that `allowLinking="true"` was set in your Tomcat config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315093/configure-symlinks-for-single-directory-in-tomcat/315145#315145
2. Check that the user of the `tomcat` process has execute permission on *every* parent folder of the `/home/developer/dev/workspace/svn/Project/webapp/` directory (i.e. `/home`, `/home/developer`, `/home/developer/dev`, `/home/developer/dev/workspace`, ...)